# Cannot add an object to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks and redux, I'm building simple CRUD Employee app, and when I try to add an employee, it comes up as null. Meaning it shows up on the array but it's blank.

here is my code.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {addEmployee} from "../../actions/employeeActions";
import FormContainer from "../layout/FormContainer";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";

const AddEmployee = () => {
    let history = useHistory()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [full_name, setFull_name] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [phone_number, setPhone_number] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(addEmployee())
        history.push('/home')
    }
```

and the reducer.

```
case ADD_EMPLOYEE:
            return {
                ...state,
                employees: [action.payload, ...state.employees],
                loading: false
            }
```

and action.

```
export const addEmployee = () => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    const response = await axios.post('api/employees', config)

    dispatch({
        type: ADD_EMPLOYEE,
        payload: response.data
    })
}
```

Please assist

Comment: Have you tried using any debuggers? Apart from that check if your reducer is in the `combineReducer` for the `rootReducer`

Comment: Yes, all the reducers trees seem fine, can't seem to find any errors

Comment: The code looks fine. Try `console.log()` in different places in your code to find out actually where the code is not performing as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should console.log() though

Comment: `console.log(response.data)` and see that it is sent it till the reducer

Answer (score 0):

When you `dispatch(addEmployee())`, you don't even pass the parameters (eg. name, email, phone...) to `addEmployee` in `action.js`. That's why you got a `null` return.

Try this:

```
export const addEmployee = (name, email, phone, address) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        // post the params as data in your axios call
        data: JSON.stringify({ name, email, phone, address })
    }

    const response = await axios.post('api/employees', config)

    dispatch({
        type: ADD_EMPLOYEE,
        payload: response.data
    })
}
```

Then dispatch

```
dispatch(addEmployee(full_name, email, phone_number, address));
```

**Edit:**

As the states still come up `null` **before** you dispatch the action (in `onSubmit()`), which mean the **states are not updated** before dispatch. Try to update your code as below:

```
<input value={full_name} onChange={(e) => setFull_name(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: That did not work either, it still comes out as undefined (null)

Comment: can you `console.log(full_name, email, phone_number, address)` in the `onSubmit` function? If the result is still undefined/null, please check your `onChange` function for the states

Comment: the onChange is just fine. the console.log(full_name, email, phone_number, address) still comes up null.  Can someone try to assist me.

Comment: You didn't even change the states that's why it comes up `null`. Well, if you would like to do some testing, try `const [full_name, setFull_name] = useState('James Bond');` and `console.log` again. I bet this time the `full_name` will show up

Comment: And the issue you currently have has nothing to do with redux! Check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html to find out more on how to update the states